# pg-node error when connecting to amazon rds database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, node-postgres

I have created a database instance using the Amazon RDS Console, assigning it the following VPC security group, authorizing any IPV4 address to connect to the database (I know this is bad practice, but I am desperate to find a solution):[image: vpc inbound rule]

I have set the public access to true: [image: public access true]

I also want to point out that the `VPC security groups` match!

I would like to connect to this database using the `pg` library: https://node-postgres.com, but I keep getting an error that says:

```bash
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "**.***.***.**" (my IP), user "postgres", database "desk_booking", no encryption
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\apps\itec2022\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\apps\itec2022\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
    at Parser.parse (C:\apps\itec2022\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\apps\itec2022\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 165,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '543',
  routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
}
```

I've read that there is no way to change the `pg_hba.conf` of a database created via RDS Console.

When I tried to connect to the database via `psql` with the exact same credentials, it worked:
[image: psql result]

I think there is a problem with the `pg` package, or how I set it up:
[image: local pg setup].

I know there is a way to bypass this, by setting

```js
ssl: {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}
```

But I feel like it's hacky and not a best practice (although I'm not sure, because it is also used in the official node-postgres documentation: https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl). I would like to know if this option is ok to use in a production environment with Amazon RDS. Does it pose any security issues? Is it safer to use in combination with `ca`, `key`, `cert` parameters (as described here: https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl)? If so, how can I obtain those values?

I also tried:

```js
ssl: true
```

which results in the following error:

```bash
Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1540:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:959:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}
```

I'm not aware of using any VPNs:
[image]

*I would like to know why the terminal is allowed access and my application is denied. Furthermore how can I solve the issue?*

Comment: "authorizing any IPV4 address to connect to the database (I know this is bad practice, but I am desperate to find a solution)" yeah this is a bad idea.  Postgres is vulnerable to DOS attacks and someone *will* find the IP addr in not too long.  Instead of allowing all IPs allow only your own IP (the Security Group rule edit console page will help you enter it).  You'll have to change it when your IP changes, but it's still the correct way.  You can run postgres pretty simply locally as well, with or without docker, which might be simpler (and will certainly be cheaper!)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html describes how to use the RDS CA so you can properly verify the cert.

Comment: You are right! I just checked the docs and it looks like RDS Postgres has a setting that requires all connections to be SSL: `rds.force_ssl = true` (default). That does open a question: while it is obvious that the app didn't have any SSL configured, how was the shell able to connect? Are all psql shell connections SSL by default?